# API call to get the list of files from s3 path in aws using boto3 python library

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, python-3.6

I am new to aws. I'm looking for python boto3 library API calls in aws for below scenarios.

1. API call to get the list of files using s3 path
2. API call to remove all the files under s3 path
3. API call to check if the given s3 path is exits or not

I appreciate If any one can help me on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Paths" (directories, folders) do not actually exist in Amazon S3. It uses a flat (non-hierarchical) storage model where the filename (`Key`) of each object **contains the full path of the object**.

However, much of the functionality of paths is still provided by referencing a `Prefix`, which refers to the first part of a Key.

For example, let's say there is an object with a Key of: `invoices/january/invoice.txt`

It has a Prefix of `invoices/` and also has a prefix of `invoices/january/`. A Prefix simply checks "Does the Key start with this string?"

Therefore, you can **get the list of files using s3 path** with:

```py
import boto3

s3_resource = boto3.resource('s3')

for object in s3_resource.Bucket('my-bucket').objects.filter(Prefix='invoices/'):
    print(object.key)
```

Or, using the `client` method:

```py
import boto3

s3_client = boto3.client('s3')

response = s3_client.list_objects_v2(Bucket='my-bucket', Prefix='invoices/')

for object in response['Contents']:
    print(object['Key'])
```

To **remove all the files under s3 path** you would need to use the above code to **iterate through each object**, and then call [`delete_object()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.delete_object). Alternatively, you could build a list of Keys to delete and then call [`delete_objects()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.delete_objects).

To **check if the given s3 path is exits or not** you can call [`head_object()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.head_object). Please note that this will work on an **object**, but will not work on a "path" because directories do not actually exist.

However, if you create a Folder in the Amazon S3 management console, **a zero-length object is created** with the name of the directory. This will make it "appear" that there is a directory, but it is not required. You can create an object in any path without actually creating the directories. They will simply "appear". Then, when all objects in that directory are deleted, the directory will no longer be displayed. It's magic!

See also: [Amazon S3 examples — Boto3 documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/s3-examples.html)